# Event delegation for objects; How to listen for events?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I listen for custom events on a javascript object? I'm trying to have a method of an app level object fire once an event is triggered, but unlike `DOM` elements, I cant register the listener for the object.

How can I structure my application to listen for triggered events, and then perfrom an action?

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var app = {};
  app.doStuff = function(){ alert("Yo!");};

  $(app).on("myCustomEvent", function(){
    alert("doing stuff");
    app.doStuff();
  });

  $("body").on('click', "#trigger", function(){
    alert("triggered");
    $(this).trigger("myCustomEvent");
  });
});
```

reporduced in a jsbin:
http://jsbin.com/zopubuso/1/edit

*The reason behind this*:

I'm creating a backbone application, in which I have a global event vent inside my `app` object. I'm trying to communiate between views by triggering events:

ie.

```
app.on("myEvent", MyView.model.doStuff);
app.trigger("myEvent");
```

But I'm unable to get the events to fire.

Comment: This library might help you: https://github.com/benjreinhart/node-event-emitter. It's a port of node.js's `EventEmitter` class that can also be used in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

trigger with jquery:

```
$(app).trigger("myCustomEvent");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9w8A5/

**trigger as backbone event:**

first You will need to extend the object with `Backbone.Events`:

```
var app = {};
_.extend(app, Backbone.Events); // underscore.js '_.extend', We can also use jquery '$.extend()'
... on("myCustomEvent")...
app.trigger("myCustomEvent");
```

**demo: http://jsfiddle.net/A5484/1/**

---

Update from agconti.

Here's a simple way to accomplish attaching events in backbone:

```
var app = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){

        ... other configuration stuff ...

        app.on( "myCustomEvent", function(){
            this.doStuff();
        }, myView);
    },
    doStuff: function(){ alert("Yo!"); }
});

app.trigger('myCustomEvent');
```

`*` its much more advantageous to use backbone's event object then attaching a listener with `app.on();` like i was trying to do.

Comment: works here, but not in my backbone project, which is what I intended my question to answer. In backbone you can use `app.vent = _.extent({}, Backbone.events);` to create a vent. There you dont need to reference app as a jquery obeject, ie. you can just use `app.trigger()` instead of `$(app).trigger()`, hence my confusion. Since you answered my question as it reads; +1 and accepted answer. But if you're using backbone: I'll ask another question and link to it.

Comment: @agconti, I'm not a great expert with backbone, but I think i know the answer.

Comment: Hey meni, I updated, your answer with how I got it to work in my app.

Comment: This is kind of a shameless plug, but I created [Beacon](https://github.com/gburghardt/beacon) as a way to do application level events decoupled from the DOM. Searching [GitHub](https://github.com) or [Bower](http://bower.io/search/) could also turn up alternatives.